# MySQL Training videos

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi were can I find training videos for MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In youtube you find somethings like 
mysql install: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQcFP3GcQ0s

mysql trainning: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHq-bORKncA

Google presentation about mysql tunning (hot) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u70mkgDnDdU

You have anothers google presentations about mysql, just search in youtube and googlevideos :-)

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget: http://dev.mysql.com/

This is a good resource to back up anything you find in any videos. I can't recommend any videos as I have no experience with them, sorry.